# Jquery pasar un parámetro de un evento .change a otra función

Tags: jquery, funciones

Hola a todos tengo un problema con este código, tengo un select y necesito obtener una variable y pasarla como un parámetro de otra función para  enviarlo a una url y así pueda ser un modificador de input de un método ya creado en laravel yo quiero obtener este parametro y pasarlo a otra función, **¿alguien sabe como se hace?**

```
 var elem = $('#typo').bind('change fadeOut', function(){
   return $(this).val();
 });

 function consumo(elem){
  $.getJSON('/stock?type='+elem,  function( data ){
    console.log(data);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Hola, creo que te hace falta agregar mas detalles ya que no se entiende del todo, ya te ayude con el formato de la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esto te puede servir:

```
var elem = $('#typo').bind('change fadeOut', function(){
    consumo($(this).val());
});

function consumo(elem){
    $.getJSON('/stock?type=' + elem,  function( data ){
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

o hacerlo directo:

```
var elem = $('#typo').bind('change fadeOut', function(){     
    $.getJSON('/stock?type='+ $(this).val(),  function( data ){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```